# PHP conditional error testing for value

Tags: php, variables, conditional-statements, evaluation

Is $var==1 the proper syntax for testing whether $var has a value?

I ask, because I'm getting a failure on a simple conditional.

Here's the code that seems to be failing:

```
if ($slcustom31==1) {$page="http://www.mydomain.com/members/page_Alpha.php";}
```

I assume that there's something wrong with the syntax, $var==1 .

++++++++
**Here's the entire conditional, if that makes things clearer:**

```
//condition 1
if ($slcustom31==1) {$page="http://www.mydomain.com/members/page_Alpha.php";} 

//condition2
elseif ($slcustom31!=1 AND $slcustom29!="") {$page="http://www.mydomain.com/members/".$slcustom29;}

//condition3
else {$page="http://www.mydomain.com/members/page_Beta.php";} 

sl_redirecttourl($page);
```

**SPECIFIC SYMPTOM:
Script ignores condition1 and condition2, defaults to condition3.**

++++
And if it helps, here's the entire (short) script:

```
$groupswithaccess="somegroup";

require_once("../slpw/sitelokpw.php");
require_once("../slpw/sitelokapi.php"); //gets value being tested by conditional

if ($slcustom31==1) {$page="http://www.mydomain.com/members/page_Alpha.php";} 
elseif ($slcustom31!=1 AND $slcustom29!="") {$page="http://www.mydomain.com/members/".$slcustom29;}//not finished, but started
else {$page="http://www.mydomain.com/members/page_Beta.php";} 

sl_redirecttourl($page);
```

Can someone tell me what I should do differently?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends. Are you trying to test if the variable has *any* value, or that it is just equal to 1?

Comment: `isset()` will determine if a variable is storing a value. If you are going to check if there is a value, you should at least check if `$slcustom31 > 0`

Comment: Ah-- that's probably the problem. I mean to test for ANY value, rather than 1.

Comment: If `$var` is 3 then obviously `3 != 1`. So a big **NO**. Also, you might want to use `&&` instead of `AND` and `||` instead or `OR`.

Comment: I tried this variant, but unsuccessfully:
if ($slcustom29>0) {$page="http://www.mydomain.com/members/".$slcustom29;}
if (isset($slcustom29)) {$page="http://www.mydomain.com/members/".$slcustom29;}

Comment: @user1968593 use backticks ( **`** ) to make SO parse something as a code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($var ==1){
//returns true only if var is 1
}

if(isset($var)){
//returns true if you currently have any value stored as the variable $var
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem I'm seeing is that the script isn't exiting the conditional when var==1. Instead, it's continuing, even though the condition has been met.

Comment: @user1968593: If that variable is set as 1 that page value should be set... if your function is not working it must either be var is not set as 1 or the function sl_redirecttourl($page); has a problem... could we see that code please?

Comment: More precisely, $var= $slcustom31 .... and that in turn is either blank, with no value, or 1.

Comment: Thanks! Since
if (isset($slcustom29)) {$page="http://www.mydomain/members/".$slcustom29;}
else {$page="http://www.mydomain/members/page_Beta.php";} didn't work, should I interpret this to mean that $slcustom29 didn't have a  value?

Answer (score 1):

To check if a variable has a value use:

```
empty($var);
```

If it's 'empty' it will return TRUE, and if not will return FALSE.
This is what's considered empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

Fore more info see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 1):

No, you want to look at [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).